# Could both cursor and all text selected be there at the same time in an EditText?

Tags: android

When I tap on an EditText, I would like to have all text selected along with the cursor at the end. How can this be achieved?

In my layout xml, I have

```
android:selectAllOnFocus ="true"
```

and I am setting the cursor using
`editText.setSelection()`. The full text gets selected, but I am not able to get the cursor at the end of the text.

I checked the android documentation for setSelection [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Selection.html#setSelection(android.text.Spannable,%20int)) and it looks like the right API to show cursor at a specific position.

Could someone please help. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length()); this will move cursor to end.

Comment: @ZohraKhan, Yes, I am using editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length()). However, with selectAllOnFocus set to true, all text selection and cursor placement is not happening together. See that's what my question is - Could I have both at the same time?